# The right noun to describe the fact that something is forbidden by the law and, therefore, is absent

Tags: word-request

> One of the cornerstones of the social system of the Communist Vietnam was
>   the **absence** of private entrepreneurship.

The idea that is meant to be expressed here is that no one was allowed to have his own private business in Vietnam. However, the word "absence" doesn't seem to convey the concept that it was forbidden. It only conveys the meaning that it was for some reason absent.

So, perhaps, "the illegality of private entrepreneurship" would fit the bill, but it may also be interpreted then as quite the opposite to what is meant to be expressed - like "the private entrepreneurship was illegal in other countries, so the leaders of Vietnam decided to build a brand-new society, where the private entrepreneurship was legal".

Comment: *prohibition*? *proscription*? *eradication*? *a complete ban on*?

Comment: @Minty I think "prohibition" would suit. What' the difference between "prohibition" and "complete ban"?

Comment: They mean pretty much the same thing, but prohibition is more formal (not too formal though). BTW I wouldn't put *the* before *communist Vietnam*, and I don't see any reason to capitalise *Communist*.

Comment: @Minty - Thanks. Can you, please, tell me what wrong meaning putting _the_ before _communist Vietnam_  produces?

Comment: If you put it in you are saying that the communist Vietnam is a different Vietnam from some other Vietnam you have in mind - today's Vietnam, I guess, although I think it is still officially a communist state. We do occasionally speak that way, but that's usually when we want to use *of*, as in *The America of Mark Twain*. It's not ungrammatical exactly, but it is unusual and in this sentence it sounds off, at least to me.

Comment: @Minty - Ah, I see. Very interesting and helpful! Thank you.